# Which is the most efficient way to bulk insert to a Oracle database?

Tags: c#, performance, oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

As a part of my requirement in office, Im required to write an C# console application that pulls bulk data from an Oracle CRM ON Demand server and pushes it to a local Oracle DB.

Now, after much research I decided to use Array Binding feature of ODP.NET which from my understanding gives the best performance.

But here's the problem, The data I'm required to pull has a total of over 50 fields/columns per record/row. So I'm required to create that many string arrays?

Can I achieve the same(Array Binding) using a data table with 50+ columns, instead of string arrays? If so, how? (I have done enough research on this and couldn't find a solution) I know I could use OracleBulkCopy class, but from what I've read here its not so efficient and the performance is poor when compared to Array Binding.

Also, Will my application be still efficient if I use so many arrays? Because when i discussed this option with my colleagues, they claim its not a good design to have so many arrays in your application.

The above concerns have had me stuck for the past few days, can anyone please help me with the best solution approach for my problem? I need this fixed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But here's the problem, The data I'm required to pull has a total of over 50 fields/columns per record/row. So I'm required to create that many string arrays?

Unfortunalely, yes. I had exactly the same problem, and I didn't find a better solution than the one you suggested. A DataTable is an option only if you want to use classic ADO.NET.

Dont't worry about performance : my application inserts 20 millions rows par days with Array Binding, and I dont't have performance or memory problem. But I agree with your colleagues, the code is not pretty.

Comment: So, if I'm going ahead with Array binding as my choice, any precautions I must take to free up the memory that the arrays might take? 

Also, an afterthought, Would lists be a better option than arrays?

Comment: The garbage collector will free the memory for you, don't worry about that. And a (linked) list will be a better choice only if you don't know in advance how many rows you will insert : it will be probably simplier and more performant to directly allocate your arrays with the right size, and to use a for loop to iterate on the datas you process.

Comment: Alright. Yes, in my case I don't know how may rows I will insert and also the number of rows I insert will also change on a daily basis depending on a criterion.

Comment: If you are inserting 2 million records in a day, how many records are you inserting in a single batch? Or - Are you inserting all the records in one shot?

Comment: How many ? It depends. In my development environment, a value between 500 and 1000 gives the best performance. In production, 2000 or 2500 (I don't remember exactly) is used. So make this number a parameter of your application, and ajust it until you find *the* optimal value :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. You've been of great help. I would have up-voted this, only if I had enough rep :)

Comment: I'm facing another issue in this approach. It almost takes 11-15 secs to process each record in the form of string arrays. All I'm doing is stringArray[index] = Object.value; (for 56 fields) And I run this in a loop for each record. Thus, each loop iteration takes about 15secs. Ofcourse, DB insertion is fast. but how do I make the string array processing faster?

Comment: Hi, I fixed the issue. It was a few recurring web-service calls causing performance issues.
But now, I'm facing an issue with error handling in array binding. When one of the record fails in a batch, the entire batch is failing to insert. So all those batches that have failed records does not get inserted. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi, does this occur often in your context ?

Comment: Well, it happens every-time there is failed record in the batch. And unfortunately, I can't predict how often it will occur.
Irrespective of which, I thought I must get it handled.

I'm currently looping through an OracleException Error object, to find out the row number of the failed record in the batch, which invariably always posts the generic description of the error(For eg:- "DML Error") as if it occured at row 0, when the failed record is at another row. And the next iteration in the loop will point that out.

Comment: Obviously it's better to use array binding when you are sure you will not insert duplicate rows... If these duplicate rows are uncommon, you may fallback to ADO.NET mass insert when the array binding fails. You will know what are the duplicate rows. But this is a lot of (boring) code to write :-(

Comment: I was hoping there must be some way to handle exceptions in Array Binding? Could kindly tell me how you handled it in your application? 
Also, Duplicate rows are not my problem. But issues like field value Length exceeds the column length or invalid datatype etc.